# Baby Boomer, Generation X, Millennials,

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the next word in the sequence Baby Boomer, Generation X, Millennials, ...?

Comment: I think you left out Gen Y.

Comment: Older than the internet ?

Comment: I doubt if there is a word that is coined to fit in the blank. You may find this interesting. Today's teenagers like being called "founders". Check this: http://www.newyorker.com/culture/cultural-comment/the-founder-generations-creation-myth

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/276264/word-phrase-to-call-people-who-born-in-the-new-millennium

Comment: Also related [What is Gen X and Gen Y?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35878/what-is-generation-x-and-generation-y)

Comment: @Cargill Millenials are Gen Y

Comment: I think H.G. Wells refers to them as "Eloi."

Comment: @Trevor D: I was being sarcastic ... "Millennials" has not caught on so much in AusE, and Gen Y is more common.

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is Brephophagist. Greek in origin -- “brephos”=baby + “-phagia”=eating + “-ist”=designating a person. The word fell out of fashion in the late 19th century (1875, specifically, from what I can find).

Answer (score 1):

People born between late 1990s to the present day may be referred to as

- Generation Z
- iGen
- Post-Millennials

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_Z)